# Qt QColorDialog - Escape Key not "eaten" (i.e. not remove from the event queue)

Tags: c++, qt, events, dialog

In my application, I have a QTableWidget with one column where the user may click to select a color.  It work correctly with the following restriction: when the user type the Escape Key, the dialog is cancelled and close as expected, but the key event remains in the queue. This lead to a second effect of this key event, when the dialog has been closed, as if the user pressed the key twice.

Here is the whole code:

```
void CChildrenConfigScreen::actionCellClicked(int row, int col)
{
   //   ui->config_children_table->selectRow(row);
   switch(col) {
      case eColChildColor: {
            CBiStateButton* cbox = reinterpret_cast<CBiStateButton*>(ui->config_children_table->cellWidget(row, 0));
            assert( cbox != nullptr );

            if( cbox->state() != Qt::Unchecked ) {
               QTableWidgetItem* cell = ui->config_children_table->item(row, col);
               cell->setSelected(false);
               // =======
               QColorDialog dialog(this);
               dialog.setCurrentColor(cell->background().color());
               dialog.exec();
               if( dialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted ) {
                  cell->setBackground(QBrush(dialog.currentColor()));
               } else {
                  // drop escape key event ???
               }
               // =======
            }
         }
         break;
   }
}
```

So, my questions:

1. Is it the normal behavior? Or a bug in Qt?
2. Am I doing something wrong?

- If yes, what?
- If not, what can I do to "eat" this event? (preferably without the hassle of creating a QColorDialog daughter class)

Comment: Used an ugly workaround setting a flag in the "else" code block, to avoid processing the event in the other place. So ugly, but things are under control and are working fine but I'd like to understand what's happening. Really weird.

Comment: will try QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter and QCoreApplication::removeNativeEventFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I implemented. Not really beautiful but the best I was able to do so far and works as required. The definition is a bit verbose but the usage is really convenient.

First, a stack based object (Android and MacOS not yet implemented, only Windows):

```
// ==============================
// Used to disable the Escape key

class CKeyEventFilter {
   public:
      typedef char KeyType;
      typedef  std::function<void()> Functor;

   private:
      class CFilter: public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
      {
         public:

         private:
            KeyType mKey;
            Functor mAction;

         public:
            explicit CFilter(KeyType key, Functor action)
               : mKey(key)
               , mAction(action)
            {
            }

            bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) override
            {
               bool stop_it = false;

#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX) || defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
               if (eventType == "xcb_generic_event_t") {
                   xcb_generic_event_t* event = reinterpret_cast<xcb_generic_event_t *>(message);
                   assert(event != nullptr);
                   // ...
               }
#elif defined(Q_OS_MACOS)
               if (eventType == "mac_generic_NSEvent" {
                   MSG  * event = reinterpret_cast<NSEvent*>(message);
                   assert(event != nullptr);
                  // ...
               }
#elif defined(Q_OS_WINDOWS)
               if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG" || eventType == "windows_dispatcher_MSG") {
                   MSG* event = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
                   assert(event != nullptr);

                   if(event->message == WM_KEYDOWN || event->message == WM_KEYUP ) {
                      if( event->wParam == mKey ) {
                         // keep stop_it to false for the key being processed
                         // but tells the 'next client' that he doesn't need
                         // to process it a second time.
                         mAction();
                      }
                   }
               }
#else
#error "Yet unsupported OS"
#endif

               return stop_it;
            }
      };

      CFilter mFilter;

   public:
      explicit CKeyEventFilter(KeyType key, Functor action)
         : mFilter(key, action)
      {
         qApp->installNativeEventFilter(&mFilter);
      }

      virtual ~CKeyEventFilter()
      {
         qApp->removeNativeEventFilter(&mFilter);
      }
};
```

Usage:

```
{
   // Workaround with this stack based object (0x1B = 27 = ascii code for Esc char)
   CKeyEventFilter filter(0x1B, []() { CMainWindow::win()->setSkipEscape(); } );

   // Example of purpose: if dialog is left with the Escape Key,
   // CMainWindow::setSkipEscape() in the lambda above will be called
   QTableWidgetItem* cell = ui->config_children_table->item(row, col);
   cell->setSelected(false);
   QColorDialog dialog(this);
   dialog.setCurrentColor(cell->background().color());
   dialog.exec();
   if( dialog.result() == QDialog::Accepted ) {
      cell->setBackground(QBrush(dialog.currentColor()));
   }
}
```

Skip the Esc key where it was in fact already processed (in this example, in the QColorDialog above, but might be a QMessageBox or any other dialog):

```
void CMainWindow::popScreen()
{
   // mSkipEscape is initialized to false in CMainWindow's constructor
   // and set by CMainWindow::setSkipEscape() in the lambda above.
   if( mSkipEscape ) {
      mSkipEscape = false;
   } else {
      if( ! mScreenStack.empty()) {
         EScreens screen = mScreenStack.top();
         mScreenStack.pop();
         this->goScreen(screen);
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this will be useful to some people.